# Error while installing EJBCA 6.2.0

Tags: jboss, ejbca

I'm trying to install EJBCA 6.2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 but the following error comes out when I do "ant deploy" command.

Before doing "ant deploy", I installed JBoss 7.1.1 and ran it.

The installing EJBCA logs are like this.

```
jee:deployServices:

jee:deployDSJBoss5:

jee:deployDSJBoss7:
 [exec] Result: 1
 [exec] Result: 1
 [echo] data-source add --name=ejbcads --driver-name="h2" --connection-url="jdbc:h2:~/ejbcadb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" --jndi-name="java:/EjbcaDS"  --use-ccm=true --user-name="sa" --password="sa" --validate-on-match=true --background-validation=false --prepared-statements-cache-size=50 --share-prepared-statements=true --min-pool-size=5 --max-pool-size=150 --pool-prefill=true --transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED --check-valid-connection-sql="select 1"
 [exec] JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [
 [exec]     ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
 [exec]     ("data-source" => "ejbcads")
 [exec] ]

BUILD FAILED
/home/mjshin/ejbca_ce_6_2_0/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while     executing this line:
/home/mjshin/ejbca_ce_6_2_0/bin/jboss.xml:289: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/mjshin/ejbca_ce_6_2_0/bin/jboss.xml:556: exec returned: 1

Total time: 4 minutes 55 seconds
root@mjshin-VirtualBox:~/ejbca_ce_6_2_0#
```

I'm not familiar with web application server environment such as ant, JBOSS, etc. so I have no idea of what I should approach this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error today when was trying to re-deploy EJBCA after changes in conf/web.properties file.
Looks like the problem is caused by having duplicate record somewhere in the JBOSS database/configuration file, could not locate where that record duplication occurs.
Resolved problem by deleting two lines in the jboss.xml which cause the problem (288 and 289).
As I understood, the line 288 (contains "data-source remove") tries to remove the old record, but it fails, the failure is ignored and execution is continued, and then and next line tries to add resource with the same name ejbcads, that operation fails, but this time failure is not ignored and deployment stops with error.
Make sure to save copy of the jboss.xml.